# Grouing data in Excel and converting to XML

Tags: vba, excel

I created a VBA code to group data according to its value.

For example:

```
(input)                    Output

colA                        colB     colC     colD

red1                          1        2        3
red2
white1                       red1     red2     green3
yellow2                     white1    black2
black2                                yellow2
green3
```

Part of my code is like:

```
   Sub Macro1()
   Dim color As Double, color1 As String

    color1 = Range("A:A").End(xlUp).Row
   color = Right(color1, 1)


    Columns("A:A").Select

    For i = 1 To 9

    If color(i, 1) = color Then
    ActiveSheet.Range ("A:A")
    Selection.Copy
    Range("D1").Select
     ActiveSheet.Paste

      End If
      Next i
      End Sub
```

But it did not work. Need somebody to guide me.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are trying to accomplish but this should set you in the right direction:
Read the comments as you step through the code to really understand it.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Dim color As Integer ' Assign as integer instead of double in order to save space/time
    Dim color1 As String

    ' Create integer variables to loop through reference worksheet
    Dim i As Integer, i2 As Integer

    ' Create a workbook and worksheet variable
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    ' Assign your workbook and worksheet variable
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' ThisWorkbook = the currently selected workbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1") ' "Sheet1" represents the tabname for the sheet that contains the range you want to reference

    ' use a "With" to work with the worksheet
    With ws

        For i = 1 To 9 ' Start First Loop
            color1 = .Cells(i, 1) ' i = row, 1 = column
            color = Right(color1, 1) ' extracts integer of 1 length on the right of the variable

            If color <> "" Then ' If there was data in column a of the current row then test if it matches otherwise skip.

                ' Take the values of and check if they match any other ones
                For i2 = 1 To 9 ' Start Second Loop

                    If Right(.Cells(i2, 1), 1) = color Then ' *** Change this to what you want to trigger the action
                        .Cells(i, 5) = .Cells(i, 5) + .Cells(i2, 1) ' *** Change this to the action you want it to do.
                    End If

                Next i2 ' End Second Loop
            End If
        Next i ' End First Loop

    End With

End Sub
```